# How to round price after applying coupon in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I've addded the below code to my **function.php**, but it didn't round the price after applying a coupon.

I'm using woocommerce 2.5.5.

This is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);

function round_price_product( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    return round( $price );
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a value in your function, instead, maybe, you need to return the `$price` variable this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);

function round_price_product( $price ){
  //Store and Return rounded price
  $price = round( $price );
  return $price;
}
```